# What does 人よ幸あれ mean?

Tags: words, nuances, definitions

I'm wondering what 人よさちあれ means in this line:

> 我がためにガラス戸張りし人よさちあれ

I think さちあれ is 幸あれ, which I've seen translated as "good luck" or "bless you," etc. But how does it work here with the 人よ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A literal translation would be "O the man who put up (this) glass door for my sake, let there be fortune (with him)!"